# Сессии в разных ЯП

Tags: php, c++, golang, сессия

Ребят, а можно про сессии. Смотрите есть общее понимае сесия это кука, которая живет на сервере, но вопрос а как именно. Просто использовал я boltdb и там специальна доп методы шли. Так все же где храниться? просто ели у меня бд другая. Или это где-то в линукс. Как все в деталях работает .

я просто из php там все автоматом делалось и я как то не задумывался

Comment: Когда это куки на сервере жили? Все это добро хранится на вашем ПК, можете погуглить, в разных браузерах в разных местах, почитайте про localStorage, будет понятнее, механизм тот же.

Comment: Если даже вопрос о сессии, то "как именно" будет ответ "в каждом случае по-разному". Прямо говоря, не понимаю, что вам даст ответ на этот вопрос. Где-то в файлах на диске, где-то в базе, где-то хоть ещё где-то. Ну и?